# How to support other languages in Azure blob storage?

Tags: asp.net, azure, multilingual, azure-blob-storage

I am developing a web application by using ASP.NET/ C# and AZURE. I am using Azure Blob to store files. I face a problem to store a file with other languages(Only English is OK).

Example: 
I save this as a .txt file :"한나라당 전당대회 돈 봉투 사건을 수사하고 있는 검찰이 박희태 국회의장 비서관 사무실을 전격 압수수색했습니다. 조정만, 이봉건 두 수석 비서관실과 여비서 함모 씨가 근무하는 부속실입니다. 서울중앙지검 공안1부는 오늘(19일) 아침 8시 20분 서울 여의도"

but when I retrive this, its shows: "í•œë‚˜ë¼ë‹¹ ì „ë‹¹ëŒ€íšŒ ëˆ ë´‰íˆ¬ ì‚¬ê±´ì„ ìˆ˜ì‚¬í•˜ê³ ìžˆëŠ” ê²€ì°°ì´ ë°•í¬íƒœ êµ­íšŒì˜ìž¥ ë¹„ì„œê´€ ì‚¬ë¬´ì‹¤ì„ ì „ê²© ì••ìˆ˜ìˆ˜ìƒ‰í–ˆìŠµë‹ˆë‹¤. ì¡°ì •ë§Œ, ì´ë´‰ê±´ ë‘ ìˆ˜ì„ ë¹„ì„œê´€ì‹¤ê³¼ ì—¬ë¹„ì„œ í•¨ëª¨ ì”¨ê°€ ê·¼ë¬´í•˜ëŠ” ë¶€ì†ì‹¤ìž…ë‹ˆë‹¤. ì„œìš¸ì¤‘ì•™ì§€ê²€ ê³µì•ˆ1ë¶€ëŠ” ì˜¤ëŠ˜(19ì¼) ì•„ì¹¨ 8ì‹œ 20ë¶„ ì„œìš¸ ì—¬ì˜ë„"

What is the problem ?

Thanks
Nahid

Comment: This is nothing to do with Azure, this is a text encoding issue.

Comment: @Chandermani is correct I think. Could you try to specify UTF-8 or UTF-16 when you read the file back? On disk files have a BOM that tells the reader what encoding the file has, but I suspect this is lost or ignored when you download the file from the blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save your text files in UTF format (not ASCII).

**UPDATE** after @naruse comment

And you have to specify the [content type property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobproperties.contenttype.aspx) for the blob including the charset. I do that for cyrillic alphabet and it works perfectly. There shall not be issues with Korean one.

If it is a plain text file, the proper value for Content Type should be:

`text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Or the charset you naturally use.

Comment: I use this. but its not working: 1. blob.Properties.ContentType = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName; 2. blob.Properties.ContentType = " charset=utf-8";
                    3. blob.Properties.ContentLanguage = Encoding.UTF8.HeaderName; But Its not working..

Comment: how about the file itself. Not only the blob properties. Did you try saving the file with some "Advanced" text editor such as NodePad++ or UltraEdit, or anything that support UTF8 encoding? So you could explicitly set Unicode encoding for the file itself. Try with and witout BOM (Byte Order Mask).

Comment: Content-Encoding is not for such usage; its value is usually gzip or deflate. It should be saved as Content-Type's charset parameter

Comment: @naruse, it appears that the problem has been solved by simply converting the files to UTF-8, but I wonder what brings you to this question and answer, which are more than 2 years old?